# Image load time makes my JS/CSS animations stutter (and I apparently don't understand preloading)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am encountering this issue while trying to create a JS/CSS animation that make images appear in various ways.
Here is a very simple codepen: https://codepen.io/fran-ois-lacruche/pen/ZEVBjQW

An image can be displayed with a button that makes it switch from display:none to display:block.
When you press the button for the first time, there is a slight delay before the image appears. But then as you press the button again & again there is no more delay because the image is cached, right. But the first delay kinda ruins the fluidity of the animation, so I'd like to fix it.

My search to solve this issue has led me to try and preload my images. That's what I want, right? That's what preloading is about, I'm not crazy...right ?!

I have tried preloading tricks such as this one:

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="img-url.jpg" />
```

or this one (commented out in the codepen, try it)

```
function preload_image(im_url) {
  let img = new Image();
  img.src = im_url;
}

preload_image("img-url.jpg");
```

I have also tried adding a will-change:transform, display, opacity.... etc.
In the case of the specific animation I wanted to make (not the codepen), I also tried setting all my hidden images to opacity:0 and making them appear with opacity:1. This works in Firefox (no delay) but not Chrome (delay). And I guess it's not a clean solution anyway.

But anyway, none of the tricks I tried work for me, be it in Chrome or Mozilla. What am I doing wrong ? Should I resort to making my images appear off-screen before actually appearing or something ?

Thank you for reading, for your help and for your time.

Comment: Open browser, F12, network tab, load page/run codepen.  The image *is* loaded when the page is loaded.  There's no "loading delay" when you click the button to load the image before displaying it.   It's unclear what the cause is, but it's *not* due to not being loaded/preloading/cache/network speed.

Comment: Update: the initial delay is caused by the browser having to resize your *huge* 4025x6037 image by recalculating it down to max500 x max500.  Download the image in the correct size and your delay goes away: https://jsfiddle.net/n1Lx80wr/

Comment: That is indeed it. See my answer to the other comment. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see the issue in your case is rather the pixel size of the image. The "preload" attribute you are trying to use is about the file itself, but in your case the file is there and already loaded when you want to use it. The problem is that browsers need to draw out the given image, and this takes longer time with bigger images.

If you can decrease your image's pixel size, then you should do that, for example add "&w=300" to your example:
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1692696602494-3c871f2a79c1?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2OTM5OTU4ODV8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85&w=300

and you will see how the delay disappears.

In case that is not a solution, as I see putting the image off-screen first doesn't really solve this issue. If it is a possibility, instead of switching the 'display' of the image, rather change its 'opacity', but you need to add some opacity even when the image is not visible:

```
opacity:0.001;
```

just so the browser would render it. This opacity is small enough to not see the image. Maybe combine it with switching the 'position' of the image too, if you don't want it to take up space:

```
img {
  opacity:0.001;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-10000;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  &.switch {
    position:static;
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```